# How to report "foreign tax paid" from 1099-DIV?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Is it correct to report Foreign tax paid in 1099-div to line 47 Foreign tax credit in 1040 form?

But here http://voices.yahoo.com/how-report-amounts-form-1099-div-2439-11819489.html?cat=3 it says that

> Any foreign tax paid by the mutual fund or REIT would be reported in
>   box 6. You could claim this tax as an itemized deduction on Schedule A
>   or as a credit on Form 1116.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **always** take deduction for foreign tax paid on Schedule A, **or** calculate foreign tax credit using [form 1116](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1116,-Foreign-Tax-Credit). Credit is usually more beneficial, but in some cases you will be better of with a deduction.

However, in very specific cases, you can claim the credit directly on your 1040 without using the form 1116. Look at the [1040 instructions for line 47](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040/ar01.html#d0e6516):

> **Exception**.   You do not have to complete Form 1116 to take this credit
>   if **all** of the following apply.
>
> - All of your foreign source gross income was from interest and dividends and all of that income and the foreign tax paid on it were
>     reported to you on Form 1099-INT, Form 1099-DIV, or Schedule K-1 (or
>     substitute statement).
> - The total of your foreign taxes was not more than $300 (not more than $600 if married filing jointly).
> - You held the stock or bonds on which the dividends or interest were paid for at least 16 days and were not obligated to pay these
>     amounts to someone else.
> - You are not filing Form 4563 or excluding income from sources within Puerto Rico.
> - All of your foreign taxes were:
>
>   1. Legally owed and not eligible for a refund or reduced tax rate under a tax treaty, and
>   2. Paid to countries that are recognized by the United States and do not support terrorism.
>
>   For more details on these requirements, see the Instructions for
>     Form 1116.

Comment: Note that the above Exception may hold true for more filers than one might initially think.  For example, if one's only exposure to foreign income is a handful of mutual funds with a total balance under, say, 200K USD, then it's quite likely that the foreign tax paid on the funds' earnings in a given year will sum to less than 300 USD.